# jQuery Display Input Value

Tags: jquery, html

I have coded the jQuery below, which should display the input value when clicked. I have tested the code, but soes not seem to display the value like it should. Any help with errors is appreciated.

http://jsbin.com/ivahit

**HTML**

```
<span id='msg'></span>

<input type='text'>

<button id='get'>Get</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("button:#Get").click(function () {

$('#msg').html($('input:text').val());

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this

```
$("button:#Get").click(function () {
```

with this:

```
$("#get").click(function () {
```

ID is case sensitive and also `button:#Get` is not a proper selector.